# Does converting a real number expressed in polar coordinates to a complex number require $3$ dimensions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I believe I have an intuition problem here as I review my complex number properties I notice the book converts a real number expressed in polar coordinates as $(r,\theta)$ to $(r\cos\theta + ir\sin\theta)$. Although the book doesn't explicitly say it. Is it not implied that the real number $(r, \theta)$ when expressed as a polar coordinate takes a one dimensional real number and associates it with another real number in a two dimensional non complex plane?

We also know any one dimensional number can be expressed as two dimensional object if you allow the real numbers to be a subset of the complex numbers. (As for example the number $1$ would be $1 + 0i$)

Now if I convert my real number $(r,\theta)$ to a complex number why does the $\theta$ all of a sudden end up as a new dimension of the complex plan? Should there not in reality be $2 r$'s? An $r$ associated with the real number and and $r'$ associated with the vertical component of the complex line? Or is that just swept under the rug to make things simple and manageable, which I am fine with. I just don't like to think I missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that $(r, \theta )$ is a real number? It is a _pair_ of real numbers.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Does each real number in the pair have an imaginary and a real component ?  How then is this pair reconciled to be converted to an imaginary number according to a standard formula ?  thanx !

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system for how a pair like $(r,\theta)$ is usually interpreted as a point in the plane (complex or otherwise).